# How can an Orchard Core module add new roles and permissions?

Tags: c#, .net-core, orchard-modules, orchardcore

IPermissionProvider doesn't seem to be able to add new roles (maybe I missed something), and it also seems to only be called during the module's initial installation, which seems batty.

How can my module add new roles and permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPermissionProvider` implements two methods which you can implement.

- `Task<IEnumerable<Permission>> GetPermissionsAsync()` which allows your module to return a `Permission` which your module provides, and
- `IEnumerable<PermissionStereotype> GetDefaultStereotypes()` which allows you to define what of the permissions you have created will have by default, and/or add a `PermissionStereotype` to define a new role.

Comment: It's only called once, when the module is initially installed. I have been able to force it to be called by manually modifying the database, so that it thinks it is a new module.

However, when I go to the roles admin screen, I see no indication that new roles have been added.

Comment: I re-tried forcing it to run -- Permissions.cs does work. As do Migrations. Thank you.

Comment: I believe it runs on module activation, so you should be able to disabled your module, then enable it, after you have made code changes, to affect roles